# MAAS install CA to new machines

Tags: ubuntu, ssl-certificate, certificate, ubuntu-16.04

How could we add custom trusted Certificate Authority to the new deployed ubuntu 16.04 machines on MAAS v2.3 ?

is there a direct way to do that, or we have to perform custom installation nodes ?

Answer (score 0):

At this point there is no direct way to add custom CA certificate during the installation. You can use **curtin**, however, to achieve your goal:

https://docs.maas.io/2.1/en/nodes-custom